# Storing Random Forests in C++

Tags: c++, string, decision-tree, random-forest

I have several serialized decision trees (currently as one long string in pre-order) generated by the random forest method. I've hardcoded these strings into the class so that all of the decision trees are created once the constructor is called. To summarize:

1. The constructor is called
2. A for loop runs over each string (representing a decision tree) and splits them into tokens
3. Each token is processed (stored in a vector of strings) and a decision tree is created

Now, my setup works correctly but since the strings are very long the string splitting can take a long time. I'd like to optimize this process but have the following things to consider:

1. I could store the strings directly as individual tokens in order to avoid string splitting altogether but then my CPP file would be very large in size due to the need for many "t.push_back(str)" statements (one for each token). This is probably a last resort.
2. I could possibly store the strings in binary but I'm not sure if this would help and it wouldn't be human readable.
3. I've also made sure that my trees have been trimmed (i.e. used as few trees as possible and applied a limit to the maximum depth)
4. C++11 is not an option in my case

I would appreciate any thoughts or suggestions on best practices or ideas.

**Update**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::string> test(int elem){
    const char* t0[] = {"t00","t01"};
    const char* t1[] = {"t10","t11","t12"};
    std::vector<std::string> s;
    switch (elem){
        case 0:
            s.assign(std::begin(t0), std::end(t0));
            break;
        case 1:
            s.assign(std::begin(t1), std::end(t1));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return s;
}

int main (){
    std::vector<std::string> t;
    t = test(0);
    std::cout << t.at(0) << std::endl;
    t = test(1);
    std::cout << t.at(2) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What about writing them as `string tokens[] = {"token1", "token2",...}`? Or even `vector<string> tokens = {...}` in C++11

Comment: I should've stated that I've considered this in my original post. C++11 is not an option in my case. I've added this point now but thank you.

Comment: `string tokens[]` is still an option

Comment: For hardcoded strings, `const char* tokens[]={...};` saves you the allocations

Comment: @Mooing Duck: I am investigating your suggestion but, currently, the function/method that generates the decision trees from the tokens takes the form genTree(std::vector<std::string> &t,...) and cannot be changed. So what would I need to do to the "const char* tokens[]={}" in order to get this to work?

Comment: `const char* tokens[2367]={...};  genTree(vector<string>(tokens,tokens+2367));` (Could be shortened in C++11 but...)